# SVG scale (center the origan)

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations, svg-animate

I need help with moving the smoke group origan to the center so it will scale with the rocket.

ii have tried to do:

transform-origan: center;
translate-box: box-fill;

to fix this problem but it seems to do nothing.

```
link: https://codepen.io/paulsanti/pen/eYydYgN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You accidentally misspelled origin. It should be `transform-origin`.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your `transform-origin` using a specific 3-axis `px` position, and it will work:

```
<g id="smoke" style="transform-origin: 761px 491px 0px">
```

Not that this is not `761px` in display pixels - it's actually 761 SVG units in the context of this SVG's coordinate system (the `viewBox`). The actual width in display pixels will be different depending on the scale it's displayed at, but you don't have to worry about that.
.
Your SVG has a `viewBox` of `0 0 1512 982`, so the exact center is x: 1512/2, y: 982/2.

(For your smoke animation, you may want to shift the origin down 120 units or so, to `transform-origin: 761px 610px 0px` to line it up with the bottom section of the rocket)